# Issue with fetching the data from URL query string

Tags: php, get, request

I have a url like `http://localhost/uploaded_server_alert/backup/alertR/business/business-registration.php?back_abn=2342&back_add1=#asdas`

I want to fetch the `back_add1` value in my page. But if I use `$_REQUEST['back_add1']` then it is not working. Please help me how to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: try `urlencode()` to encode the URL, and then fetch its value.

Comment: Your code is equal to the questioner's one in this case. `$_GET` will only see parameters sent via URL, `$_REQUEST` handles both, `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: then please suggest how to do that?

Comment: `urlencode($foo)` where `$foo='#asdas`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: do that where you form your URL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode the character `#` as `%23`, try like this

```
http://localhost/uploaded_server_alert/backup/alertR/business/business-registration.php?back_abn=2342&back_add1=%23asdas
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a blank result because of the #. # is an anchor tag. If you have an element in your page with name `asdas`, the page will scroll down there.

Comment: then is there any change to get "#asdas" into variable.

Comment: Not with PHP. With Javascript you can get it by doing `window.location.hash`. Make the link without the hash. If needed, you can manually add it afterwards in PHP.